JWT | Does anyone know why JWT generated via AMPscript is diferrent than generated via JWT.io
Ref link1 = AMPscript JWT = https://ampscript.guide/getjwt/

Ref link2 = JWT official site = https://jwt.io/

Comparison link = https://www.diffchecker.com/tEwnbx5h/



JTW generated via AMPscript
JWT generated via jwt.io
Comparison











Could possibly be due to either AMPScript or jwt.io removing (or not removing) the spaces/tabs and newlines in the payload data. Based on the screenshots alone, it looks like you may not have pasted the entire payload into jwt.io

For the benefit of other readers who may happen upon the question - the question is a XY Problem. JWT RFC 7519 - whitespace is explicitly allowed in the representation and no canonicalization need be performed before encoding.

Yep, this is a difference in whitespace.
jwt.io strips out tabs, spaces, newlines, and carriage returns
AMPScript is leaving them in
I'm not going to type out all of the Base64URL data you've given (text is MUCH BETTER than screenshots alone, as per usual), but since the first 2 parts of a JWT are just plaintext, base64url encoded, it's not too much trouble to type out the first part of the claims/payload (at least enough to confirm what's going on)
ew0KICAiQ29u -> \x7B\x0A\x20\x20\x22\x43\x6F\x6E
7B = the opening curly brace
0A = a newline
2020 = 2 spaces
22 = double quote
43 = C
6F = o
6E = n
and
eyJDb -> \x7B\x22\x43
7B = the opening curly brace
22 = double quote
43 = C

Thanks @Derek :)
